# Tiff manipulation multiple thread C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

someone experienced on manipulation of a Tiff file (using BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET)?

I need to use multiple thread to modify a big image for a better performance.

The calculation over the image a masking of the image for create 2 diffrent images with the positive and negative mask (for example an operation like that):

`buffer2[y][x] = (byte)(buffer[y][x] & maskBuffer[y % maskTiffHeight][x % (maskTiffWidth * tiffBpp / 8)]);`

Any suggest?

Thank you

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try that and seems working:

```
Parallel.For(0, sourceBuffer.Length, i =>
                    {
                        destbuffer[i] = new byte[sourceBuffer[i].Length];
                        destbuffer2[i] = new byte[sourceBuffer[i].Length];
                        Parallel.For(0, scanlineSize, y =>
                        {
                            destbuffer[i][y] = (byte)(sourceBuffer[i][y] & maskBuffer[i % maskTiffHeight][y % (maskTiffWidth * tiffBpp / 8)]);
                            destbuffer2[i][y] = (byte)(sourceBuffer[i][y] & ~maskBuffer[i % maskTiffHeight][y % (maskTiffWidth * tiffBpp / 8)]);
                        });
                    });
```

Thanks for the reply Bernhard.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Likely bad luck for you: bitmap manipulation functionality provided by Windows (and likely used somewhere in the background by that library) does not work with several threads.

For improving performance, you should use (single-threaded) *unmanaged* code.

Comment: If I split the tiff image in a multiple Bitmap object I cannot do that?

Comment: Can you show me an example of that? I use very big image and masking that I have to wait many time to the end of the manipulation.